# Finding restricted API calls on Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, marketplace

I've been trying to get a WP8 app certified in Marketplace for about two months now, and it gets bounced back every time with the 5.1.4 code and a "silently exits every time" error.  The only  thing that I can imagine would cause this error would be restricted calls lurking somewhere in my project or included library (even if the code isn't actually called, just having it in a linked library is enough to trigger the silent exit).

I've tested it on emulators and physical devices and it works like a charm.  Unfortunately, the restricted API checking only happens on Marketplace-installed apps.  Even if it does crash, I have a top-level "unhandled exception" handler to wired up to write crash data (used in all my apps).  Since it crashes immediately, it never gets to pop up a message to email me anything.

WP7 had a feature in the Store Test Kit (and on submission) that did static analysis to check for forbidden calls, but this seems to be missing from WP8 now.

Does anyone know of a way to get around this?  Is there a tool I don't know about to detect the problem?  Can I force the emulator or my own physical device to show me detect the problem to provide me with more data?  I'm at my wit's end!

Comment: Could be a missing capability in the manifest. When you submit your app, your code is analyzed and the manifest is automatically re-generated. There already has been a few cases of capabilities needed but not correctly detected.

Comment: What would I do about that though if it happens in submission?  I simply can't recreate the issue on physical device or emulator, and the WP8 Store Test Kit doesn't verify capabilities anymore anyway.

Comment: Reading a few more places, I may have come across a way to at least see the error in action by publishing it as beta.  I hadn't thought of that yet.

Comment: Well, by publishing in beta I can now see the problem on my own hardware.  Of course I can't debug it, and I don't think I can get to iso storage anymore either.  It starts and exits so quickly, I can't imagine that any application code is even executed.  Definitely no error handler is invoked.  Now I guess it's just lots of trial and error.  There has to be some way to detect what's happening!

Answer (score 0):

The Store Test Kit **is** still there. It's a bit of a pain to find though. Right click on your app project in Visual Studio's Solution Explorer.

It seems a bit counter-intuitive but the automated test cases do still do static analysis (.NET and native code) when you follow  "Click the Run Tests button below to run the automated test cases". The results show on the "XAP Package Requirements" line as shown below.

[image: Picture of Store Test Kit for WP8].

Are you sure you're logging all your exceptions, even from background threads?

Now you have an app in beta you should be able to see the crash logs on the Dev Portal (eventually).

Comment: The Test Kit is there, but without static analysis for WP8.  For exceptions, I'm handling Application_UnhandledException in App.xaml.cs, so that should be everything. The problem is when a Marketplace-installed app uses an undeclared capability *or* a restricted API in an agent, the app immediately exits. Even if it logs the error, it won't matter since it can't show it due to the instant crash! I could check iso storage for a logged error, but it *only* happens in certification. I can't recreate it. It's been about ten submissions now where I tweak and test and spin the dice and try again!

Comment: XAP Package Requirements definitely does static analysis - I'm looking at some failures right now :).

Comment: Doesn't the submission process show you which capabilities it has detected? Can't you update your WMAppManifest.xml with just that set of capabilities?

Comment: In Store Test Kit/Automated Tests, it has options to validate the XAP (just the files, icons, and screenshots).  What static analysis options do you see Paul?  Regardless, it doesn't show any errors for me.  The caps shown when I create the Marketplace submission match what I've set in the manifest.